Can anything but bank cards be added to Apple Wallet?
I recently put my bank cards into Apple Wallet, and it seems to have been a good idea.
It would useful if I could add my library card, Costco membership card, etc., but when I try to add anything, all it does is provide me with a long list of credit and debit cards that it's willing to accept.
(They don't need to "tap", the image on the screen would be all that's needed.)
Is there some way of adding non-financial cards to Apple Wallet?
In case it matters, this is in Canada.

Lots of things can be added to Wallet. Airline boarding passes, hotel memberships, covid vaccinations. But the applications that create these things have to contain code to do it, you can't just add random cards yourself.

You can try online services. For example Passsource appears to have Costco card template.

The Apple Wallet is designed for "cards" which allow the iPhone to authorise payments, hotel room access, etc. via contactless Near Field Communication (NFC).
It is possible to add some cards which will be used by displaying a barcode which can be scanned in store, library, or wherever. As well as this being limited to particular types of card, it often has not worked very well for me.
As an alternative there are iPhone apps which do store a wide range of cards for which the barcode can be displayed on screen for a reader.  I experimented with a few, and Stocard seemed much the best.
I use Stocard Australia for my cards. As well as accepting almost any kind of card, it displays barcodes on screen brighter and larger than anything I have seen in Apple Wallet.  This provides reliable scanning even with the comparatively primative barcode readers at my public library.
In Canada see Stocard Canada, but any country specific site links to the appropriate Apple App Store.
I have no connection with Stocard except as a user.

I tried Stocard and it works well.  Thanks.
¶　It seems very strange though that two applications are required, one for RFID cards and one for bar-code cards.

Even stranger. Stocard has an option to copy the bar-code card into Apple wallet, but, again strangely, not the two that I would care about, Costco and my library.

@RayButterworth Even for cards that Stocard can put into the Apple Wallet, I found the Stocard app to be better - bigger and brighter display of barcodes.

Three months later, Stocard gets eaten by Klarna and now it's totally useless.  [sigh]

@RayButterworth I use Stocard without a login so I did not get the notification about Stocard.  Will see what happens.

Apple Wallet has built-in support for payment cards. For just about everything else, it requires that some other app include support for loading its data into Wallet.
Many stores have apps, and some of those apps will have an option to save your membership card in Wallet. For instance, Walgreens has this option. Unfortunately, Costco doesn't.
You can't just load random cards, like library cards, into Wallet. And even if you could, it wouldn't do much good if the library doesn't have a way to use digital cards when checking out.

My library card, Costco card, various points cards, and other things have bar-codes on them that could be scanned from the screen. The Wallet wouldn't require any knowledge of what these cards actually are. It seems like such an obviously good feature for Wallet to provide, that I surprised it doesn't.

Wallet is not just a scanner, it actually encodes information about the card and the application. Of course, you can take a picture of your card, and if the library will allow you to use that image in their checkout system, you can do that.

"if the library will allow you to use that image in their checkout system, you can do that." — Yes, I could create a Google Photo album of the cards, but it wouldn't have anywhere near the efficiency of access or convenience that the Wallet provides.

Unfortunately, that's how Wallet works. It's not an image repository.
